# Calling a separate android activity from a background thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jetty

I have been trying to embed the `Jetty WebServer` inside my android app so that the app can act as a `WebServer`.

I have been able to do so using `AsyncTask` so that it runs in background. Then, I also have been able to instantiate a few servlets which function as expected.

Now in one of the servlets, I want the servlet to call an `Activity` to allow users to log in and provide some data and return those data to the servlet so that they can be sent back to the user. Since the servlet is running in background, I am struggling to call the activity from the servlet.

Now,I would like to know if there is any way to do so.

Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the constructor of your AsyncTask, take a Context object as a parameter and store it locally. Now when you need to start the next Activity, use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Next.class);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

The AsyncTask will be something like:

```
public AsyncTask MyTask...... {

    Context mContext;

    public MyTask(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

}
```

And to create it use:

```
MyTask myTask = new MyTask(getBaseContext());
myTask.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried this one before. The problem is the servlet is in a separate class which extends HttpServlet. Once it receives It then calls a method of another class inside which I will need to call the activity. I have passed the context reference to the class from where I will need to make the call to activity. At this point, it throws Null Pointer Exception. Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: After comparing my code with your code one more time, I found the error. Thanks for leading me to find the error.